# Find a value in Kotlin Data Class

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, data-class

i'm actually new to Kotlin android development. I'm making an app that uses Google sheets as a database. My app can successfully run after Google sign in. In fact I want my user to sign in to app, if their email ID is present in the Emails sheet in the Google sheet. So I have done following steps in my code so far.

1. Sign in user with Google Sign In
2. Retrieve data from "Emails" sheet in my Google Spreadsheet
3. Then store them in to a data class (Customers data class in Shipment.kt)
4. Then I check whether signed in user's email ID available in the data class or not. This is where I need help. It's giving me this error
   **"Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly."**

Can someone help me on this?

Below is my data class in Shipment.kt

```
package com.example.demoonlinesheet

data class Shipments(
    val shipperName:String,
    val volume:String,
    val eta:String,
    val etd:String)

data class Customers(
val companyName:String,
val customerName:String,
val emailID:String)
```

Below is the code that I have written so far in MainActivity.kt

```
const val RC_SIGN_IN = 123
const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.demoonlinesheet.MESSAGE"
const val EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.example.demoonlinesheet.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    var mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    sign_in_button.setOnClickListener{
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }
    val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)

    if (acct != null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply{
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, acct.displayName)
            //putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, acct.email)
        } )

    }
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {

    val companyList= arrayListOf<Customers>()
    val url="https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetID}/values/{sheetName}?alt=json&key={APIKey}"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        {
            fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {

                try {
                    // val feedObj = response.getJSONObject("")
                    val entryArray = response.getJSONArray("values")

                    for (i in 2 until entryArray.length()) {
                        val entryObj = entryArray.getJSONArray(i)
                        val companyName = entryObj[0].toString()
                        val customerName = entryObj[1].toString()
                        val emailID = entryObj[2].toString()
                        //  entryObj.getJSONObject("gsx\$lastname").getString("\$t")
                        companyList.add(Customers(companyName, customerName, emailID))

                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }, {
            fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError?) {

                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Fail to get data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        })
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)

    fun checkUser() {
        val getAccount = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        val emailLoggedIn = getAccount.email.toString()
        val companies = listOf<Customers>()
        //this is where I get the error message "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly."
        if (emailLoggedIn in companies){
            //do something here
            
        }


    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        val loggedname = account.displayName
        //startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java))
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, loggedname)
        }
        startActivity(intent)

    } catch (e: ApiException) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
if (emailLoggedIn in companies) {
    //do something here
}
```

`emailLoggedIn` is a `String`, `companies` is a `List<Customers>`.

How does `List` know how to compare `String` and `Customers`? :)

You need something like this:

```
if (companies.any { it.emailID == emailLoggedIn }){
    //do something here
}
```

I should also mention that you can leave the if condition unchanged and add the following code that overloads the `in` keyword:

```
operator fun List<Customers>.contains(email: String): Boolean {
    return this.any { it.emailID == email }
}
```

But, in my opinion, this overload looks terrible and confusing :)

Comment: hi @plplmax, I have removed my fun checkUser () and put if condition inside my try catch block. but even if I have correct email ID in the sheet user cant logged in.

'try {
 val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
 val emailLoggedIn = account.email.toString()
 val loggedname = account.displayName
 val companies = listOf<Customers>()
 val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, loggedname)
            }
            if (companies.any {it.emailID==emailLoggedIn}) {
startActivity(intent)
}
} catch (e: ApiException) {
}'

Comment: @IshanSasanka, try replacing `for` with `for (i in 0 until entryArray.length())`

Comment: I did the change but still the same. Cant log in. Any suggestions?

Comment: @IshanSasanka, you can set breakpoints and debug your logic line by line. It's easier than guessing)

Comment: I started debugging & find out that I'm not getting data from json array (from that Google Sheet link) to the data class Customers. Now I'm trying to figure what am I missing.

Comment: @IshanSasanka, if you are talking about the `companyList` variable, I'll try to guess that you need to put a call checkUser(JSONObject) in the onResponse() method, because Volley gets data asynchronously and your `companyList` is empty after `queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)`

Comment: I could finally get pass through it. Now, how can I get the company name of the user that logged in from that `companyList`. I was searching through google but couldn't find an answer. I tried companyList.filter and could get the companyName, customerName, emailID from the data class Customers. But i'm unable to get only the companyName from it. Can you help?

Comment: sorry for the trouble. Finally, after debugging the app I was able to get the companyName of the user that logged in. However, I am not sure is this correct or not. is there a shorter version of below?

`                if (companyList.any {it.emailID==emailLoggedIn}) {
                    val findComapny = companyList.filter { it.emailID==emailLoggedIn }
                    val companyName1 = findComapny.component1()
                    val finalCompany = companyName1.companyName
                    println(finalCompany)
                    startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @IshanSasanka, `val findedCompany = companyList.find { it.emailID == emailLoggedIn } ?: return
    println(findedCompany.companyName)
    startActivity(intent)`

Comment: I used above code but it says 'return' is not allowed here.

Comment: @IshanSasanka, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels